# Response code: 400 Bad Request Error in Jmeter 4.0. Need assistance in fixing this error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, bad-request, blazemeter

I am using JMeter 4.0 for recording & running performance tests. I am also fairly new to this tool and for the 1st time, I'm getting Error 400 Bad request for which all the tests are failing. I am recording a website through VPN & trying it to run the test the same way as I did before.

Can you please help me with this. I can provide additional screenshots and details as & when you say required.

**Sampler Result:**

Thread Name: Converse_Chat_No 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-06-06 14:29:19 IST
Load time: 1313
Connect Time: 1104
Latency: 1313
Size in bytes: 1639
Sent bytes:1982
Headers size in bytes: 554
Body size in bytes: 1085
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 400
Response message: Bad Request

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 06 Jun 2018 08:59:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1085
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=hCxbUY5Kq+Vdfv1jhO/JGeLqCqRHT281vZy+T4LFgJCRnItYwGILJLnD3KPsv5wYlVGiy85bYqVH75PSlLNCLcPPDTDtgGHoXAKbw9T8QoT6WPxPm6qVI4tyG7H1; Expires=Wed, 13 Jun 2018 08:59:22 GMT; Path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8

Answer (score 0):

As per [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request **due to invalid syntax**.
>
> `The client should not repeat this request without modification.`

So most probably you're sending malformed requests which server doesn't understand.

The only troubleshooting technique I can think of is recording requests which real browser sends using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) and comparing them to what JMeter sends. The requests should be the same (apart from dynamic data which has to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations))

As soon as you amend your JMeter test plan to 100% match requests which are being sent by the real browser it should start working. Don't forget about [Cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and [Headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).